# Upload file to Supabase renders path.replace is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, supabase

So i am trying to upload a file to Supabase with this code:

```
async function uploadCv(e) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from("uploads").upload(file);
  }

return (
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => uploadCv(e)} />
)
```

and it renders this weird error:

path.replace is not a function
TypeError: path.replace is not a function
at StorageFileApi._removeEmptyFolders (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25189:17)
at StorageFileApi. (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24713:32)
at Generator.next ()
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24660:67
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24642:10)
at StorageFileApi.uploadOrUpdate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24694:12)
at StorageFileApi. (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24755:19)
at Generator.next ()
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24660:67

Does anyone have any idea what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: Check this [doc](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-upload). First parameter should be file path and the second one should be file body.